# How to expand any particular tree structure from the opened Eclipse Help menu

Tags: eclipse

I am opening the Help menu as `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp();`
Now I want to open the help window with any of the available menus in expanded format.
How to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WorkbenchHelper.getHelpSystem().displayHelpResource(...);
```